# Pip not updated? How to Find User?

Tags: python, pip

> python3 -m pip install pynput
> Collecting pynput
> Using cached pynput-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (99 kB)
> Requirement already satisfied: six in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from pynput) (1.15.0)

I have already installed pynput apparently, but it says my pip is not updated and I can't upgrade my pip because of users?

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip-20.2.3.dist-info/RECORD'
> Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Comment: press windows key, right click, run terminal (cmd) as administrator

Answer (score 1):

No, it told you to user the `--user` placholder like this:
`pip3 install pynput --user`
Use this one and you will see this working. Or You can use virtual environments to avoid this error.